# Pygame music play start position seems to have a 1 second resolution

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-mixer

I'm using `pygame.mixer.music.play` to load and play a wav file as follows:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
wavfile = "/my/wav/file.wav"
mixer.music.load(wavfile)
start = 0.5
mixer.music.play(start=start)
```

However, `start` seems to have a 1 second resolution. In other words, any float acts as if it was truncated to its whole number part. This is unexpected because the [documentation of pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play) shows that the start position is a float given in seconds. In fact, investigating the source, you can see that `mixer.music.play` is just a thin wrapper around the SDL library's `Mix_FadeInMusicPos` ([documented here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2_mixer/Mix_FadeInMusicPos)). Those docs also show a float second start time.

Is this a limitation of the wav format, the library, or am I specifying something incorrectly here?

Comment: How are you confirming that the wav didn't start at .5?

Comment: The wav file is very distinctive. It's easy to tell that it's starting at 0 or 1. It's only about 1.3 seconds long, and regardless of what I specify, it seems to round to truncate to 0 or 1.

Comment: I have encountered a similar delay due to a wireless headset. Does this delay occur with native speakers? Can you trim the `.wav` file to test just the section you need? I've used [audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) to modify files in this way.